# zf2 tablegateway select columns with join table

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have this code (which works fine):

**Class SsoRequserTable**

```
public function fetchAll()
    {
        $select = new Select();
        $select->from("sso_requser");       
        $select->join('sso_workunit', 'sso_workunit.sso_workunit_id = sso_requser.sso_workunit_id', array("unitname"), 'left');
        echo $select->getSqlString();
        $result = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
        return $result;

    }
```

**class SsoRequser**

```
class SsoRequser{
    public $sso_requser_id;
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $fullname;
    public $sso_workunit_id;

    public function exchangeArray($data){
        $this->sso_requser_id = (!empty($data['sso_requser_id'])) ? $data['sso_requser_id'] : null;
        $this->firstname = (!empty($data['firstname'])) ? $data['firstname'] : null;
        $this->lastname = (!empty($data['lastname'])) ? $data['lastname'] : null;
        $this->fullname = (!empty($data['fullname'])) ? $data['fullname'] : null;
        $this->sso_workunit_id = (!empty($data['sso_workunit_id'])) ? $data['sso_workunit_id'] : null;

    }
}
```

**Module.php**

```
public function getServiceConfig() {
        return array(
            'invokables' => array(
//                     'Aclplugin' => 'Auth\Controller\Plugin\Aclplugin',
            ),
            'factories' => array('SSO\Model\SsoRequserTable' => function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('SsoRequserTableGateway');
                    $table = new SsoRequserTable($tableGateway);

                    return $table;
                },
                'SsoRequserTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('postgresql_adapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new HydratingResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setObjectPrototype(new SsoRequser());
                    return new TableGateway('sso_requser', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },


            ),
        );
    }
```

But I can`t get the sso_workunit columns to work. I have read the Zend Documentation and nothing effectively worked for me. I need name to have an alias "unitname".

And i got the message error "`Undefined property: SSO\Model\Entity\SsoRequser::$unitname` "

Whether I should add unitname in class SsoRequser ?
Anyone can help me ?